# docker-compose: mariadb - Connection refused

Tags: mysql, docker, phpmyadmin, docker-compose, mariadb

**Step 1) mysql5 & phpmyadmin**

Image the following mysql-phpmyadmin configuration:

```
version: '3.6'

services:

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.24
#    image: mysql:8.0.18
#    image: mariadb:10.4.8
#    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - ./mysql5:/var/lib/mysql
#    - ./mysql8:/var/lib/mysql
#    - ./mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=test
    - MYSQL_USER=test
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=test

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:4.8.5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
    - db
    environment:
    - PMA_HOST=db
    - PMA_PORT=3306
    - PMA_USER=test
    - PMA_PASSWORD=test
    ports:
    - "3333:80"
```

I can access my **mysql-database** via phpmyadmin: http://localhost:3333/

**Step 2) mysql8 & phpmyadmin**

Now I switch to mysql8, where I only the image and volume and added the `command`-option with the `mysql_native_password`-plugin:

```
version: '3.6'

services:

  db:
#    image: mysql:5.7.24
    image: mysql:8.0.18
#    image: mariadb:10.4.8
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    volumes:
#    - ./mysql5:/var/lib/mysql
    - ./mysql8:/var/lib/mysql
#    - ./mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=test
    - MYSQL_USER=test
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=test

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:4.8.5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
    - db
    environment:
    - PMA_HOST=db
    - PMA_PORT=3306
    - PMA_USER=test
    - PMA_PASSWORD=test
    ports:
    - "3333:80"
```

I can access my **mysql-database** via phpmyadmin: http://localhost:3333/

**Step 3) mariadb & phpmyadmin**

Now I switch to mariadb with the following configuration, where I only changed the image and volume:

```
version: '3.6'

services:

  db:
#    image: mysql:5.7.24
#    image: mysql:8.0.18
    image: mariadb:10.4.8
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    volumes:
#    - ./mysql5:/var/lib/mysql
#    - ./mysql8:/var/lib/mysql
    - ./mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=test
    - MYSQL_USER=test
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=test

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:4.8.5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
    - db
    environment:
    - PMA_HOST=db
    - PMA_PORT=3306
    - PMA_USER=test
    - PMA_PASSWORD=test
    ports:
    - "3333:80"
```

Now I cannot access my **mariadb-database** via phpmyadmin:

[image]

Following the mariadb-README on [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb), the environment configuration should be the same as for the mysql5-container. I assume, that I also need to enable the `mysql_native_password`, which does not work as for the mysql8-container.

What do I miss? Is this a bug or do I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for `mariadb` with `--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password`, just the container start is really slow.

[Edit] Here is a MWE, which works with different mysql-versions (5 and 8) and the newest mariadb (10):

- https://github.com/boldt/docker-compose-mariadb-mysql-phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

Your docker-compose file works. I start **MySQL** container than switch to **MariaDB** image and it's working fine. I think you should look into docker logs. The answer is there

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB doesn't have `default-authentication-plugin` option. That might be the reason