# phpMyAdmin does not connect to MariaDB and MariaDB does not set default MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD variable on the docker compose

Tags: docker, phpmyadmin, docker-compose, mariadb

I'm trying to create a `docker-compose` with [MariaDB](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb) and [phpMyAdmin](https://hub.docker.com/r/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/) Docker images, however I'm having the following problems: neither MariaDB nor phpMyAdmin use the environment variables inside their files, in other words, MariaDB does not set default password described on MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD variable and phpMyAdmin is not able to connect to MariaDB even if I set a new password to MariaDB manually.

On the terminal, MariaDB shows the following output when I run the docker compose for once:

```
dgi_catalog_db       | PLEASE REMEMBER TO SET A PASSWORD FOR THE MariaDB root USER !
dgi_catalog_db       | To do so, start the server, then issue the following commands:
dgi_catalog_db       | 
dgi_catalog_db       | '/usr/bin/mysqladmin' -u root password 'new-password'
dgi_catalog_db       | '/usr/bin/mysqladmin' -u root -h  password 'new-password'
dgi_catalog_db       | 
dgi_catalog_db       | Alternatively you can run:
dgi_catalog_db       | '/usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation'
[...]
dgi_catalog_db       | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
```

When I try to connect to MariaDB through phpMyAdmin without setting a default password, the following message shows:

```
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused
```

Then, I get into the container and I set a new password manually:

```
$ docker exec -it dgi_catalog_db /bin/bash

# mysqladmin -u root password 'password'
```

If I try to connect through phpMyAdmin again, I get the same error again:

```
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused
```

Then, I tried to restart my containers and to connect through phpMyAdmin again and they show the following messages:

- phpMyAdmin on the web interface:

```
Packets out of order. Expected 0 received 1. Packet size=69
mysqli_real_connect(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=35
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away
```

- MariaDB on the terminal:

```
dgi_catalog_db       | 2020-01-15 12:36:36 8 [Warning] Aborted connection 8 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.29.0.3' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
```

I've already tried some solutions on the internet (for example, this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58577346/8447990)), but I was not able to fix the problem.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS and I send my files below.

Could anyone help me, please? Thank you in advance.

**project's structure**

I have a folder called `catalog` with the following structure:

```
.
├── docker-compose.yml
└── env_files
    ├── db.env
    └── phpmyadmin.env
```

The files are described afterwards.

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3'

services:
  dgi_catalog_db:
    container_name: dgi_catalog_db
    image: mariadb:10.4.11
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ../data/mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql
    env_file:
      - ./env_files/db.env
    networks:
      - dgi_catalog
    ports:
      - 3311:3306

  dgi_catalog_admin:
    container_name: dgi_catalog_admin
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:4.9
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - ./env_files/phpmyadmin.env
    networks:
      - dgi_catalog
    ports:
      - 8099:80

networks:
  dgi_catalog:
    driver: bridge
```

`../data/mysqldata` volume can be another folder.

**./env_files/db.env**

```
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
```

**./env_files/phpmyadmin.env**

```
PMA_HOST=dgi_catalog_db
PMA_ARBITRARY=1
```

**EDIT 1:**

I've not found a solution, but I believe I've discovered the main problem: MariaDB takes a very long time to initialize. 20 minutes after docker-compose be initialized, MariaDB has printed `mysqld: ready for connections.` and I was able to connect to my database through phpMyAdmin.

```
dgi_catalog_db       | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
dgi_catalog_db       | 2020-01-15 14:06:41 10 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@% root@fbbf075da453' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
dgi_catalog_db       | 2020-01-15 14:06:41+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Stopping temporary server
[...]
dgi_catalog_db       | 2020-01-15 14:06:49 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@% root@fbbf075da453' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
dgi_catalog_db       | 2020-01-15 14:06:49 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
dgi_catalog_db       | 2020-01-15 14:06:49 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
dgi_catalog_db       | 2020-01-15 14:06:49 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
dgi_catalog_db       | Version: '10.4.11-MariaDB-1:10.4.11+maria~bionic'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
dgi_catalog_db       | 2020-01-15 14:06:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200115 14:06:49
```

There is an opened [issue](https://github.com/docker-library/mariadb/issues/261) on Github about it. Apparently, if I use the `-e MYSQL_INITDB_SKIP_TZINFO=1` variable, MariaDB will initialize faster, but I will not have time zone information.

Comment: Can you share your project's structure? `env_file`'s path should be relative to `docker-compose` file's location.

Comment: I've added the project's structure to the question. Yes, `env_files` folder is a relative path, it exists inside my project's root folder. Thank you.